# Why is this LPF design passing frequencies above resonant in such magnitudes?

Tags: noise, low-pass

It's been a while since I have worked with filtering so I decided to simulate a circuit to see what I had forgotten. I used MultiSim for my circuit simulations but will present the design using the schematic tool on Stack Exchange. I designed a RC LPF like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5S8gS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I inserted the AC power supply as a source of electrical noise; this source is an RMS supply - so the oscillations of 1V RMS are actually about 1.4V. Here is the plot of only the noise voltage.

[image]

The resonant frequency of this RC network is 5kHz. As such, my thought was that most of the 10kHz signal should be attenuated. To make sure I ran an frequency sweep in Multisim to verify my predictions.

[image]

Looked good to me. We should expect approximately -7.24 dB at 10kHz (which is about 0.188*noiseVoltage = 0.188*1.4 = 263mV). That is to say, I was expecting the output voltage to vary from 12V +- 263mV.

This is what I saw when I ran transient analysis on the circuit. I set -12V DC offset on the sinusoidal voltage source so the plot would display only the noise component.

[image]

We are actually seeing 607mV fluctuations at the output; this is about 43% of the total amplitude available before the LPF. The attenuation is high as expected, but not quite as high as I was thinking it would be.

I must be missing something here. Any ideas?

Comment: Just as a technical aside, a single-pole filter doesn't have a "resonant" frequency, it merely has a "corner" frequency, at which the impedances of the resistor and capacitor are equal in magnitude, giving a 3dB drop in power at the output.

Comment: I see. I do recall this now that you mention it.  I suppose only bandpass/reject filter (and the like) would resonate. Putting it that way is a bit confusing though. If the impedance of the two loads are equivalent (thinking voltage divider) then wouldn't you expect Vout to to be half the the supply? (assuming no internal resistance at the supply). Perhaps the fact the capacitor is not a purely resistive load comes into play here thereby attenuating the supply by 0.707 rather than 0.5

Comment: Yes, the capacitor is a purely reactive impedance, so it has a 90-degree phase relationship to the resistance. The vector sum has a magnitude of 1.414x either one alone.

Answer (score 4):

I think your calculation for the attenuation is wrong. A gain of -7.24 dB correspond to an attenuation of 10^(-7.24/20) = 0.43. That implies that the 1.4 volts sinusoid should appear with an amplitude of 0.6[V], which match with you simulation.

Remember that *voltage* gain in dB is given by \$G_{V}=20\log(G)\$. It seems you're using the formula for *power* gain, given by \$G_{P} = 10\log(G)\$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was improperly using the dB conversion. Actually, I was calculating power in dB (10log .. ). Thanks!